# Proving limits with the epilson delta definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

1. I want to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not exist using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits.
   I know I need to algebraically prove that for $0<|x|<\delta$, $|\sin(1/x) - L| ≥ \epsilon$  , but I'm not sure how.
2. How can you show that the  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: For the first part, show that $\sin(1/x)$ is equal to $1$ and $-1$ for arbitrarily small values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcI/defnoflimit.aspx) is a definition of limit.

Both problems are easy:
I am giving a hint for $2nd$ problem.
$$|f(x)-f(0)|=|xsin\frac{1}{x}|\leq |x-0|<\delta$$,
Choose $\delta=\epsilon$
$$|f(x)-f(0)|\leq \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

For first question is enough to consider sequences $x_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Both tends to $0$ but $\sin$ have different fixed values $0,1$ in them, so it is not possible to have limit.

For second, as already mentioned, is enough to use $|\sin x| \leqslant 1$ and use $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x = 0$.